# Get selected radio button from radio group (ExtJS)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm looking for proper function in ExtJS which will bring me back a selected radio button from radio group, is there anything like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ext.form.BasicForm there is a method called getValues() you can pass the id of the control and it will return its value

```
formPanel.getForm().getValues()['radioGroup'];
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all, who helped me to find out the tricky one..
here is my solution

Ext.getCmp('form_window_id').getForm().getValues(['radioGroup_id']).groupname

it works fine in ExtJs3.4...

--Ashish